# Coalesce/IsNull on stored proc output parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure:

```
[checkCultureCode]
@InputCulture varchar(5) = 'en-US',
@ValidCulture varchar(5) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @ValidCulture = CultureName FROM Culture 
    WHERE CultureName = @InputCulture 
SELECT @ValidCulture = COALESCE(@ValidCulture, 'en-US') 
    -- or ISNULL(@ValidCulture, 'en-US')
END
```

I would expect to get one of the following:

- value of `@InputCulture` returned back to me (if it exists in the `Culture` table)
- 'en-US' if `@InputCulture` was null
- 'en-US' if `@InputCulture` was not null but also not an existing value eg. 'evil'

But I get `null` when I do this:

```
DECLARE @v varchar(5)
    EXEC checkCultureCode 'evil', @v
SELECT @v;
```

This works and I get 'en-US' as the answer:

```
DECLARE @v varchar(5)
    SELECT @v = CultureName FROM Culture WHERE CultureName = 'evil' 
    SELECT @v = COALESCE(@v, 'en-US')
SELECT @v;
```

I had hoped that writing all this down would help me see the difference, but I still can't. I would like to use a stored proc and output parameter so that I can execute this check from another stored procedure.

Comment: You need an additional SELECT to get the value of @ValidCulture, see my answer.

Comment: Since none of your logic requires an alteration to data you could actually use a UDF rather than a stored proc. You would not have to mess with OUT params that way. Your usage would be simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the parameter as OUTPUT in the call to your SP.

```
DECLARE @v varchar(5)
EXEC checkCultureCode 'evil', @v OUTPUT
SELECT @v;
```